# Arithmetic overflow error converting money to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server-2005

This is my query I am inserting  a values in the in the temp table, but I am getting the error like this..

> Arithmetic overflow error converting
>   money to data type numeric.

Query is:

```
DECLARE @EBT money
Declare @ConversionRatio money
Declare @TotalRevenues money

insert into #SummarySheet(Item,INR,Dollar,Percentage) 
VALUES ('EBT', isnull(@EBT,0), isnull(@EBT,0)/isnull(@ConversionRatio,0), 
         isnull(@EBT,0)/isnull(@TotalRevenues,0))

FYR:
```

The values are:

```
@TotalRevenues="1.00"
@EBT="-50995944.26"
@ConversionRatio="44.5"
```

How to rectify it....

Comment: isnull(@TotalRevenues,0) as a divisor, and isnull(@ConversionRatio,0). That's not correct

Comment: Then that is the formula....or i should change the declaration of datatype

Comment: I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: What is the **structure** of the table?? What types are those columns `INR`, `Dollar`, `Percentage` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table isn't money.

It's numeric (decimal): and not wide enough for the calculated value

Also, to avoid divide by zero errors, these 2 calculations

```
isnull(@EBT,0)/isnull(@ConversionRatio,0)
isnull(@EBT,0)/isnull(@TotalRevenues,0)
```

should be

```
isnull((@EBT / NULLIF(@ConversionRatio,0)), 0)
isnull((@EBT / NULLIF(@TotalRevenues,0)), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Arithmetic overflow error**

> Destination data type do not have
>   capacity to handle the space
>
> kindly increase the space